# Including an external file in racket

Tags: include, scheme, racket

I would like to include all the functions defined in a given racket file so that I get the same effect as if they were copied. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `include` as follows:

Create a file called `"foo.rkt"` that looks like this:

```
(define x 1)
(define y 2)
```

Then in another file:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/include)
(include "foo.rkt")
(+ x y)
```

You should see the result `3`.

You can see the documentation for [`include`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/include.html) as well.

Comment: Sam, please read [Racket language questions tagging: tags "plt-scheme" and "racket"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74042/147036).

Comment: Sorry to awaken an old thread, but why is there no #lang racket in foo.rkt?

Comment: @Manbroski there is no `#lang` because `foo.rkt` isn't a module, it's just some definitions. `#lang` creates a module. If we did that, we'd be trying to include a module inside our module, which isn't what we want.

Comment: How can I do it while having `#lang` in `foo.rkt`?

Answer (score 27):

To export the functions out of a module, you use `provide`, consider a file `"foo.rkt"`:

```
#lang racket
(define fortytwo 42)
(define (det a b c)
  (- (* b b) (* 4 a c)))
(provide (fortytwo det))
```

The file `"bar.rkt"` now can import definitions from `"foo.rkt"`:

```
#lang racket
(require "foo.rkt")
(define (baz a b c)
  (+ (det a b c) (- c 4)))
```

The other way you could allow other files to have access to everything that’s defined in the file, is using `(all-defined-out)`:

```
#lang racket
(define fortytwo 42)
(define (det a b c)
  (- (* b b) (* 4 a c)))
(provide (all-defined-out))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note also that there is `include`, which might be what the question was originally about.

Comment: somehow include didn't work in my case, but your solution did the job.

Comment: I believe the right syntax to export those two functions fortytwo and det is `(provide fortytwo det)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use load

```
(load "assert.scm")
```