# Racket module import basics

Tags: module, scheme, racket

I'm trying to `require` one file in another while working with Racket. I have two files in the same folder. They are `world.rkt` and `ant.rkt`.

`world.rkt`:

```
(module world racket
  (provide gen-grid gen-cell)

  (define (gen-cell item fill)
    (cons item fill))

  (define (gen-grid x y fill)
    (begin
      (define (gen-row x fill)
        (cond ((> x 0) (cons (gen-cell (quote none) fill)
                             (gen-row (- x 1) fill)))
              ((<= x 0) (quote ()) )))

      (cond ((> y 0) (cons (gen-row x fill)
                           (gen-grid x (- y 1) fill)))
            ((<= y 0) (quote ()) )))))
```

`ant.rkt`:

```
(module ant racket
  (require "world.rkt")

  (define (insert-ant grid x y)
    (cond ((> y 0) (insert-ant (cdr grid) x (- y 1)))
          ((< y 0) 'Error)
          ((= y 0) (begin
                     (define y-line (car grid))
                     (define (get-x line x)
                       (cond ((> x 0) (get-x (cdr line) (- x 1)))
                             ((< x 0) 'Error)
                             (= x 0) (gen-cell 'ant (cdr (car line))) ))

                     (get-x y-line x))))))
```

Now, I can type `(require "ant.rkt")` in the REPL, and then when I type `(gen-cell 'none 'white)` I get the error:

```
reference to undefined identifier: gen-cell
```

I've looked up documentation on imports and exports, but I can't get it to import correctly. I feel like it's something really simple that I just don't understand about the syntax.

How should I change my code so that I can use `gen-grid` and `gen-cell` in `ant.rkt`?

Comment: maybe you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809433/including-an-external-file-in-racket

Comment: No, that question is asking about `include` for module-less code.  But in this question dbmikus is already using modules, so he's in a better starting point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks fine, and when I tested it there were no problems.

But note two things:

1. It is *much* better these days to start your code with `#lang racket` (or `#lang racket/base`).  Not only has this became the convention, it allows using whatever syntactic extensions the language provides you with, whereas `module` means that you're using the default sexpr.  (BTW, it's also more convenient in that you don't need to make the module name be the same as the file name.)
2. Using `load` with modules is probably doing something different than what you think it does.  It's really best to just avoid using `load`, at least until you know exactly what it's doing.  (It is exactly as bad as `eval`.)  Instead, you should always stick to `require`.  And when you learn some more, you can see that sometimes `dynamic-require` is useful too, but just keep `load` out for now.

Comment: Eli, you don't mention what to use in place of 'load'; I'm assuming that you're suggesting either using 'require' or just calling racket with the file on the command-line.

Comment: Ok, I switched my code up a little bit. It is now reflected in the question. I can type `(require "ant.rkt")`, but then when I call `(gen-cell 'none 'white)` I get an error message saying that `gen-cell` is undefined. It seems like it should import `"world.rkt"`. How can I fix that?

Comment: Ah, that makes a much easier answer: you should either `require` `world.rkt` from the repl too, or re-`provide` the `gen-cell` binding from `ant.rkt`.  For example, see `all-from-out`.

Comment: So you're saying I only ever need one of `#lang racket` and `(module ...` Do I interpret this correctly? Does this mean it automatically creates a module when I write `#lang racket`?

Comment: Yes, and yes -- but `#lang racket` can provide more stuff than `(module...)`, and as time passes more functionality depends on it.

Comment: Would it make sense to update the answer to reflect the new question?

Comment: @LeifAndersen, I think so, assuming that you'll keep the encouragement for  using `#lang` instead of `(module ...)`.