# Racket, include, require and provide don't work

Tags: racket

I have a file with the name “functions.rkt”, where I have some functions.

And I am working in another file, let’s name it “working.rkt”

I have tried the following (one by one) at “working.rkt” to use the function defined at “functions.rkt”:

```
(require “functions.rkt”)

(include “functions.rkt”)

(provide “functions.rkt”)
```

And anyone of them hasn’t worked, any help?

They are in the same path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including an external file in racket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809433/including-an-external-file-in-racket)

Comment: Maybe you are missing line 1 or 2:
    1. #lang racket
    2. (require racket/include)
    3. (include "functions.rkt")

Comment: This is file "funcitons.rkt": #lang racket (define (my-add x y) (+ x y)) And this is "working.rkt": #lang racket (require racket/include) (include "functions.rkt"). Then, I can't use "my-add" at "working.rkt"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the file "functions.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(provide my-function)
(define (my-function x) (* 2 x))
```

In the file "working.rkt":

```
#lang racket
(require "functions.rkt")
(my-function 21)
```

Comment: Perfect!! Now is working properly. Thank you very much

Comment: is there any way to "provide" access to all the functions within a file without explictly writing each name?

Comment: `(provide (all-defined-out))`