# require vs load vs include vs import in Racket

Tags: import, module, include, racket, require

The Racket docs indicate that Racket has separate forms for: [`require`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html?q=require#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._require%29%29), [`load`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval.html?q=load#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._load%29%29), [`include`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/include.html?q=include#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Finclude..rkt%29._include%29%29), and [`import`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/creatingunits.html?q=import#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Funit..rkt%29._import%29%29). Many other languages only contain one of these and are generally used synonymously (although obviously with language specific differences such as `#include` in C, and `import` in Java).

Since Racket has all four of these, what is the difference between each one and which should I be using in general? Also if each has a specific use, when should I use an alternative type? Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470743/racket-include-require-and-provide-dont-work) seems to indicate that `require` (paired with [`provide`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html?q=provide#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._provide%29%29)) is preferred, why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## 1. Require

You are correct, the default one you want is almost always `require` (paired with a `provide`). These two forms go hand in hand with Racket's [`modules`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-basics.html) and allows you to more easily determine what variables should be scoped in which files. For example, the following file defines three variables, but only exports 2.

```
#lang racket   ; a.rkt
(provide b c)
(define a 1)
(define b 2)
(define c 3)
```

As per [the Racket style guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/style/), the provide should ideally be the first form in your file after the `#lang` so that you can easily tell what a module provides. There are a few cases where this isn't possible, but you probably won't encounter those until you start making your own Racket libraries you intend for public distribution. Personally, I still put a file's `require` before its `provide`, but I do sometimes get flack for it.

In a repl, or another module, you can now require this file and see the variables it provides.

```
Welcome to Racket v6.12.
> (require "a.rkt")
> c
3
> b
2
> a
; a: undefined;
;  cannot reference undefined identifier
; [,bt for context]
```

There are [ways to get around this](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html?q=require%2Fexpose#%28form._%28%28lib._rackunit%2Fmain..rkt%29._require%2Fexpose%29%29), but this serves as a way for a module to communicate what its explicit exports are.

## 2. Load

This is a more dynamic variant of require. In general you should not use it, and instead use [`dynamic-require`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html?q=dynamic-require#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._dynamic-require%29%29) when you need to load a module dynamically. In this case, `load` is effectively a primitive that `require` uses behind the scenes. If you are explicitly looking to emulate the top level however (which, to be clear, you almost never do), then load is a fine option. Although in those rare cases, I would still direct you to the [`racket/load`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/load-lang.html?q=racket%2Fload) language. Which interacts exactly as if each form was entered into the repl directly.

```
#lang racket/load
(define x 5)
(displayln x) ; => prints 5
(define x 6)
(displayln x) ; => prints 6
```

## 3. Include

Include is similar to `#include` in C. There are even fewer cases where you should use it. The `include` form grabs the s-expression syntax of the given path, and puts it directly in the file where the `include` form was. At first, this can appear as a nice solution to allow you to split up a single module into multiple files, or to have a module 'piece' you want to put in multiple files. There are however better ways to do both of those things without using `include`, that also don't come with the confusing side effects you get with include.<sup>1</sup> One thing to remember if you still insist on using `import`, is that the file you are importing probably shouldn't have a `#lang` line unless you are explicitly wanting to embed a submodule. (In which case you will also need to have a `require` form in addition to the `include`).

## 4. Import

Finally, `import` is not actually a core part of Racket, but is part of its [unit system](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mzlib_unit.html?q=racket%2Funit). Units are similar in some ways to modules, but allow for circular dependencies (unit A can depend on Unit B while Unit B depends on Unit A). They have fallen out of favor in recent years due to the syntactic overhead they have.

Also unlike the other forms `import` (and additionally `export`), take [signatures](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/creatingunits.html?q=racket%2Funit#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Funit..rkt%29._define-signature%29%29), and relies on an external [linker](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/invokingunits.html?q=define-values%2Finvoke-unit#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Funit..rkt%29._define-values%2Finvoke-unit%29%29) to decide which actual units should get linked together. Units are themselves a complex topic and deserve their own question on how to create and link them.

## Conclusion (tldr)

TLDR; Use `require` and `provide`. They are the best supported and easiest to understand. The other forms do have their uses, but should be thought of 'advanced uses' only.

<sub><sup>1</sup>These side effects are the same as you would expect for `#include` in C. Such as order being important, and also with expressions getting intermixed in very unpredictable ways.</sub>

Comment: A mentionable difference between `require` compared to the RNRS `import` is that `require` will automatically shadow earlier language defined or previously required bindings. eg. `#lang racket/base` has `map` that does not allow different sized lists to be passed while `(require srfi/1)` will overwrite it with a different implementation that stop at the shortest list. In RNRS  you need to exclude one since importing same from two sources is considered an error.

Comment: Good point.  `require` will automatically shadow bindings from the `#lang` (module langauge). However it will not shadow previous required bindings (unless you're in a repl, then it will.) Also local definitions will similarly automatically shadow require definitions.